# Override javascript confirm box

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I am trying to override javascript confirm box with [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/).
I have researched also about this but I can't found proper solution.

I am using `confirm` like this

```
if (confirm('Do you want to remove this assessment') == true) {
   //something
}
else {
   //something
}
```

And I am using this for overriding

```
 window.confirm = function (data, title, okAction) {
                swal({
                    title: "", text: data, type: "warning", showCancelButton: true, confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55", confirmButtonText: "Yes", cancelButtonText: "No", closeOnConfirm: true, closeOnCancel: true
                }, function (isConfirm) {
                    if (isConfirm)
                    {
                        okAction();
                    }
                });
                // return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
            };
```

Now confirm box is replaced with sweetalert.
When user click on `Yes` button then `OK action` of confirm box should be called. But this isn't calling

And In above code an error occurred `Uncaught TypeError: okAction is not a function`.

Please suggest me I should I do for override confirm box.

Answer (score 1):

Since the custom implementation is not a blocking call, you need to call it like

```
confirm('Do you want to remove this assessment', function (result) {
    if (result) {
        //something
    } else {
        //something
    }
})


window.confirm = function (data, title, callback) {
    if (typeof title == 'function') {
        callback = title;
        title = '';
    }
    swal({
        title: title,
        text: data,
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes",
        cancelButtonText: "No",
        closeOnConfirm: true,
        closeOnCancel: true
    }, function (isConfirm) {
        callback(isConfirm);
    });
    // return proxied.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Comment: My project development is almost done and In whole code confirm is used like this `if(confirm("something")){  }` or `if(confirm("something")==true)` I want one function to override this and I cant change all confirm boxes like your code. So please tell something like that.